# Using Intersect Tool in ArcGIS gives empty output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, buffer, intersect, warning-000117

I'm currently searching for correlations between pavement conditions and crashes on highways.

I created a 420ft buffer layer for my selected highways and now I am intersecting it with  a layer for crash points. By looking at the map I can clearly see that there are points which intersect with my buffer layer, but The new intersect layer is empty with nothing in the attribute table.

I am getting a [warning-000117](/questions/tagged/warning-000117) from Intersect.

Did I do something wrong?

I'm certain I followed the correct procedure for buffering and intersecting, but I end up with nothing.

Comment: Are you getting a [tag:warning-000117] from Intersect?

Comment: yes. that error code shows in my results. I am a student and don't have enough knowledge of gis to know what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Often, when this occurs, it is possible that you have features selected that are outside the expected intersection area.

Try running the tool again, but this time, clear any selections.

Comment: I have tried clearing all selections but that does not work. I keep getting the 000117 error code in my results

Comment: @Battansa check your coordinate systems are all the same and that your data in each has values that are sensible i.e. No values that look meters in a geographic coordinate system and no values that look like lat/long in a projected coordinate system.

Comment: Everything is in NAD_1983_Oregon_Statewide_Lambert_Feet_Int. All data is within a sensible range.

Answer (score 0):

Your task sound more like the usecase of a spatial join and no intersect. A spatial join will give you a summary for all points within your pavement condition objects. You can get with the tool the number of points together with different statistics for number-attributes for each object in your buffer layer.

Comment: I've considered using a different tool, however this is part of an assignment where I am given step-by-step instructions. This step requires me to use the intersect tool, and after conferring with peers I know that it can work, but for some reason it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the solutions given to no avail I decided to start the entire assignment over. I deleted my geodatabase and shp files and redownloaded them from the source. After coming back to the same step again, the intersect tool is working now. I posted this question on my 2nd start over of the assignment. It seems that "3rd time's the charm" applies to this.